# Finding median of a list using quick select and median-of-medians

Tags: c, median, quickselect, median-of-medians

Suppose A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. I have to find the median here which is 5 and I am required to use the concept of quick select and median-of-medians. I have made the following code but for some reason, it outputs 4 which is wrong. Where could I have gone wrong?

The following are just some auxiliary functions needed for the latter functions.

```
int quick_select(int A[], int p, int r, int k);

void swapElements(int* i, int* j)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = temp;
}
void insertion_sort(int A[], int from, int to)
{
    for(int i = from; i < to; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j > from && A[j] < A[j - 1]; j--) {
            int temp = A[j - 1];
            A[j - 1] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

For the following, I made the code for median-of-medians. What this does is that it partitions the whole array into groups of 5 elements and at most 1 group containing less than 5 elements.

```
int median_of_medians(int A[], int p, int r){
    int N = (r-p)+1;
    int numberOfGroups = ceil((double)N/(double)5);
    int groupsOf5 = floor((double)N/(double)5);
    int lessThan5 = numberOfGroups - groupsOf5;
    int *arrayofMedians = (int*)malloc(numberOfGroups*sizeof(int));
    int rank = floor(((double)N+(double)1)/(double)2); //floor((N+1)/2)

    //sort each groups
    if(N>=5)
    {
        int ctrLeft = 0, ctrRight = 4;
        for(int j=1; j<=numberOfGroups;j++)
        {
            insertion_sort(A,ctrLeft,ctrRight);
            if(j<groupsOf5)
            {
                ctrLeft = ctrLeft + 5;
                ctrRight = ctrRight + 5;
            }
            else if(lessThan5>0)
            {
                ctrLeft = ctrRight + 1;
                ctrRight = N-1; //ctrRight+1+((N-1)%5);
            }

        }
    }
    else if(lessThan5!=0)
    {
        int ctrLeft = 0, ctrRight = N-1;
        insertion_sort(A, ctrLeft, ctrRight);

    }

    //find median from each group then put each median to arrayofMedians
    int ctr = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<numberOfGroups; j++)
    {
        if(j<groupsOf5)
        {
            arrayofMedians[ctr] = A[2+(j*5)];
            ctr++;
        }
        else
        {
            int rem = N % 5;
            if((rem % 2)==0) //if even
            {
                arrayofMedians[ctr] = A[(5*groupsOf5) + ((rem/2) - 1)];
            }
            else //if odd
            {
                arrayofMedians[ctr] = A[(5*groupsOf5) + (((rem+1)/2)-1)];
            }
            ctr++;
        }

    }

    //for(int i=0; i<=numberOfGroups-1; i++)
        //printf("%d ", arrayofMedians[i]);
    //Find median from arrayofMedians

    int finalMedian = quick_select(arrayofMedians, 0, numberOfGroups-1,rank);

    return finalMedian;
}
```

This is now the part where it partitions the array using the median found in median-of-medians

```
int median_partition(int A[], int p, int r){
    int median = median_of_medians(A, p, r);
    //find index ind of median
    int ind;
    for(int j=p; j<=r; j++)
    {
        if(A[j]==median)
            ind = j; //we found the index
    }

    swapElements(A+ind, A+r); //then swap A[ind] with A[r]


    int x = A[r];
    int i = p-1;
    for(int j=p; j<=r-1; j++)
    {
        if(A[j]<=x)
        {
            i++;
            swapElements(A+i, A+j);
        }
    }
    swapElements(A+(i+1), A+r);
    return(i+1);
}
```

This is the function for quick_select

```
int quick_select(int A[], int p, int r, int rank){
    if(p==r)
        return A[p];
    int q = median_partition(A, p, r); //median_partition(A, p, r)
    int k = q-p+1;
    if(rank==k)
        return A[q];
    else if(rank<k)
        return quick_select(A, p, q-1, rank);
    else
        return quick_select(A, q+1, r, rank-k);
}
```

this is the function for the main()

```
int main(){
    int T, M, *arr;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T > 0){
        scanf("%d", &M);
        arr = (int*)malloc(M*sizeof(int));

        //read the elements of the input array
        for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }

        int median_index = ((M+1)/2);
        printf("Median: %d\n", quick_select(arr, 0, M-1, median_index));
        T--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code would be easier to check if you would use a single code block with all functions. One option to check for errors is to run your program in a debugger and check intermediate results to find out what part(s) of your program is(are) responsible for the error. It is also advisable to test single functions individually. To do this it would help to document your code: Write comments that describe the purpose of the functions and how the output is calculated from the input.

Comment: The one used in [qsort](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-166/stdlib.subproj/qsort.c.auto.html) is generally a version of [Bentley, McIlroy, 1993 Engineering](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8162&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     int finalMedian = quick_select(arrayofMedians, 0, numberOfGroups-1,rank);
> ```

Here `rank` is wrong - it is set to the middle of array `A`, but should rather be the middle of array `arrayofMedians`. Change to:

```
    int finalMedian = quick_select(arrayofMedians, 0, numberOfGroups-1, ctr/2);
```

Also in the function `int median_of_medians(int A[], int p, int r)` you're indexing array `A` always from index 0 on, while indexing should rather start at `p`. To correct this, insert `A += p;` near the start of the function.

Comment: Omg this has absolutely worked! I love you! Lol. Can you further explain about the A+=p? I don't completely understand what its purpose is.

Comment: I understand it now. Haha. You don't have to explain tho. Anyway, thank you so much for saving my life!